# Unable to create dmg executable for Mac OS with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: macos, deployment, dmg, .net-core-2.1

I'm learning how to deploy .NET Core applications to multiple platforms, and I am unable to produce a `.dmg` executable for the Mac OS.

This is my development environment:

- Windows 10 Professional 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2017 Professional with latest update
- Targeting .NET Core 2.1

To test the deployment process, I created a simple "hello world" .NET Core Console App. I followed the [steps on the official MSDN website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156) to deploy the application to Mac OS in Visual Studio as a Self Contained Deployment package, but I don't see a `.dmg` file in the published target directory. I only see `.dll` files and other project related files. I also tried to publish to the Mac OS as a Self Contained Deployment package via the .NET Core CLI by issuing the following commands, but that still did not produce the `.dmg` executable:

`dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r osx-x64`

I also tried:

`dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r osx.10.13-x64`

How do I create the `.dmg` executable?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer the direct question, but I have a correction for how you're thinking about it: a .dmg file is not an executable, it is a container format, a bit like a .zip or maybe .iso. It's used to protect an actual executable (or installer package, or whatever) as it's distributed/transferred/stored/etc.

Answer (score 2):

A .[dmg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) is not an executable, it's a disk image (as Gordon wrote, something like an .iso). It can be used for distributing software, and I wouldn't expect your tools to output a .dmg (nor do Apple's own development tools).

"Self contained deployment" package in this case means that the .NET runtime is statically linked inside your executable, so the end user does not need the .NET runtime installed (at the cost of increasing the size of your binary). See [self-contained. NET core applications](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx).

Your build should be producing an MACH binary (probably with the same name as your project, without any extension). You can distribute this binary how you like, including using a .dmg. You can use [hdiutil](https://ss64.com/osx/hdiutil.html) to create and manipulate Apple disk images.

Comment: Nicely explained. I do see the elf file with no extension in the publish directory. Is this the actual executable file for the Mac which the deployment method produced? Do I just rename this file to apend the `.app` extension and then use this file to create the `.dmg` image with hdiutil?

Comment: No. A .app is a "package" of various files (the executable, resources, etc). See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html. There's no reason you shouldn't be able to create an .app for your executable, but you will need to create the correct structure.

Comment: Minor correction: macOS uses the [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) format for executables, not elf.

Comment: Thanks, fixed @GordonDavisson